# Are these points on the same plane?

Tags: vectors, plane-geometry

I must discover if these points are on the same plane:
A=(0;1;-2) B=(-1;2;0) C=(-3;4;-2) D=(-2;3;-2)
I know that this implies:
$\overrightarrow{AB}$=$\lambda\overrightarrow{AC}$+$\tau\overrightarrow{AD}$

$\left(\begin{array}\\{-1}\\{1}\\{2}\end{array}\right)$=$\lambda\left(\begin{array}\\{-3}\\{3}\\{0}\end{array}\right)$+$\tau\left(\begin{array}\\{-2}\\{2}\\{0}\end{array}\right)$

But the problem is that the z will never be 2 no matter what $\lambda$ or $\tau$. If I switch $\overrightarrow{AC}$ with $\overrightarrow{AB}$ it results, why?

Comment: The problem is that $\vec{AC}$ and $\vec{AD}$ are collinear, so you can't use them both to define your plane -- they only define a line.  I've provided an alternative approach below which I think is easier to understand (if you know that $B=A+\vec{AB}$ is the way that addition works in affine spaces).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plane is determined by three points.  The plane determined by $A$, $B$, and $C$ is $$P(s,t) = A + s\vec{AB}+t\vec{AC}$$  Notice that $\vec{AB}$ is not a scalar multiple of $\vec{AC}$ so this is in fact a plane (a $2$-dimensional affine space).  It is clear that plugging each of $A$, $B$, and $C$ into this equation you can find a solution $(s,t)$ that solves it.  But if it's less than clear just notice that $$A=A+0\ \vec{AB}+0\ \vec{AC}\quad \implies A=P(0,0) \\ B=A+1\ \vec{AB}+0\ \vec{AC}\quad \implies B=P(1,0) \\ C=A+0\ \vec{AB} + 1\ \vec{AC}\quad \implies C=P(0,1)$$

Now check whether there's a solution when we plug $D$ in.  If there is then $D$ is in the same plane as $A$, $B$, and $C$.  If not, then it's not.